# Dynamic variables with two variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bash scripting question. I am trying to create the following code, however, it does not work properly. This leads me to wonder if it is even possible. I hope someone on here can figure it out.

```
MYSQL_DB_MyDatabase_USERS_username_PASSWORD=Password

DATABASE_NAME=MyDatabase
DATABASE_USER=username
DATABASE_PASS_TEMP=MYSQL_DB_${DATABASE_NAME}_USERS_${DATABASE_USER}_PASSWORD

echo $DATABASE_PASS_TEMP
```

I would want the output to be "Password" (the original variable). I am getting an error and I know I have incorrect syntax. I have googled around and found that using one variable in the variable name, one would use echo "${!DATABASE_PASS_TEMP}", but that does not work when using two dynamic variables. Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 2):

Use BASH's **variable indirection**:

```
echo "${!DATABASE_PASS_TEMP}"
Password
```

Comment: +1 Actually it is more known as variable indirection. But your answer is correct nonetheless.

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using an associative array would tidy things up some:

```
declare -A MYSQL_DB_PASSWORDS=(
    [MyDatabase,username]=Password
)

DATABASE_NAME=MyDatabase
DATABASE_USER=username

DATABASE_PASS_TEMP=${MYSQL_DB_PASSWORDS["$DATABASE_NAME","$DATABASE_USER"]}
echo "$DATABASE_PASS_TEMP"
```

Password